# How can I transfer data while generating it using REST API?

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

How can I transfer data while generating using REST API without storing it in any temporary memory storage?

Basically I have some data stored in database which ideally I needed to write to a file, store it in server and transfer to client. But server have space restriction and not allowing me to store so large file. What should I do in that case?

Comment: Explain your question properly

Comment: @Abhijeet Edited my question with a explanation. Not sure if still it is well explained or not :(

Comment: what is the size of the file? Are you creating the file from database records and want to transfer it to client?

Comment: @Abhijeet The file size could be GBs and answer is "Yes" to your second question.

Comment: chunked encoding response any use? If the data coming from the database is too large for the server to handle, try paging through the database query result set and using chunked encoding to send it all back https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28768508/restful-api-chunked-response-for-bulk-operation

Comment: @codebrane Basically the data that I have in database have to be converted to some other format before sending and hence I'm doubtful about the synchronicity.I guess pagination requires to know the data size and here it is not known as it will be required to generate and send simultaneously.

Comment: Pagination will not require data size, Even if your database records have 1M+ records, you can first retrieve the count of records and retrieve data by defining some page size for which you want to create the file and transfer this chunked file part.

Comment: Hey @getsuha, can you move forward with my solution?

Comment: Are you just sending the raw data from the DB back to the client? Why not exposing the DB to the client directly in first place? What is the benefit of adding in an additional layer that basically does nothing? Anyway, most DB frameworks nowadays allow to stream through results, moving the DB cursor just bit by bit until either no further results are present or requested. This would be an ideal solution in your case IMO. SO and google will provide you with more than enough sources

Comment: @Abhijeet Your solution is not a good fit for me because I do not have any server with extra space.

Comment: @RomanVottner I needed to do some data processing before sending and I don't want to store that process data anywhere rather want to send it directly to client. Can you point me to some streaming cases where streaming is not done from a stored data, rather from a data processed and streamed on the fly.

Comment: just use chuncked encoding. The chunks will come from each limited pull from the database into a small file on the server. Pull 100 records at a time? Process the contents of the file and send to client. Delete the file, pull the next page from the db resultset into a new file. Repeat until finished.

Comment: @getsuha Most DB access layers such as [JPA 2.2](https://vladmihalcea.com/whats-new-in-jpa-2-2-stream-the-result-of-a-query-execution/), [spring-data](http://knes1.github.io/blog/2015/2015-10-19-streaming-mysql-results-using-java8-streams-and-spring-data.html), [JOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/java-8-and-sql), [Speedment](https://dzone.com/articles/query-databases-using-java-streams), ... allow to return the result sets as Java streams and work upon the stream before returning the results via terminal operations.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this best approach for your scenario, If anyone has a better solution than this please provide. The constraint is that you have limited size on your server. following is my approach to solve your problem

1. Currently, you have one REST API (FilePart API) which is deployed on one server which has limited storage. (let's call it server 1)
2. Make this FilePart REST API deployed on server 1 to create file parts (instead of the whole file) based on pagination data and return generated part file.
3. Deploy one more application (FileCombine API) on a different server (let's call it server 2) which will call FilePart REST API on the server 1 and sends pageNo and pageSize as parameters. This call will accept generated filePart as response and stored on server 2.
4. FileCombine API will make multiple calls to FilePart API until all parts get downloaded.
5. Once all parts get downloaded on server 2, FileCombine API will combine all the fileParts and send it back to the client.

So your architecture will be like.

> Client --calls--> FileCombineAPI(Server 2) --mutliple calls-->
>   FilePartAPI(Server 1)

Server 1: Limited space.

Server 2: Enough space to handle operation.